# How do i set up a static route between 3 routers on a packet tracer?

Tags: static, routes

i have 3 routers on my packet tracer: r1, r2 and r3.
i connect r1 and r2 using a DTE/DCE cable on serial ports s2/0
and r2 and r3 using DTE/DCE cable on serial ports s3/0

i basically do this on each of these routers:

```
    R1>enable
    R1#configure terminal
    R1(config)#interface sX/0
```

//Here X means the respective port numbers for any routers

```
    R1(config-if)#ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
    R1(config-if)#exit
    R1(config)#exit
    R1#write
    R!#exit
```

i assign different ip addresses for each gateway i.e.
For router r1 and interface s2/0, ip address is: 192.168.1.1
For router r2 and interface s2/0, ip address is: 192.168.1.20
For router r2 and interface s3/0, ip address is: 192.168.2.1
For router r3 and interface s3/0, ip address is: 192.168.2.20
after the above steps are done for all routers(and gateways), i do static routing:

```
    R1(config)#ip route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.20
```

but somehow the routers just won't ping..not even themselves.
this used to work before but i'm missing something here and i don't know what
please help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's simple my friend, you are not using `ip route` command.  Just use it and give the next hop address and remote network.  A router is used to connect two networks so we need to give the next hop, I mean the next network address.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I'm giving the static routing for the IP addresses you've mentioned.

On Router 1, set this static routing. 
192.168.2.0 via 192.168.1.20,

On Router 3, 
192.168.1.0 via 192.168.2.1

Good Luck.

Comment: The question is not on-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help]. Please don't answer such questions; instead, you should flag them for attention and they will be closed or migrated appropriately.

Answer (score -2):

Use iproute command like you have 2 router (R1 and R2)

Next go to R1 router and write commands with ip address of Router2 (Ip route Ethenet Ip range + subnet mask + serial ip)

Enter

Ctrl+z for save

Enter

now to go Router 2 and write router 1 ip with serial.

Enter

Ctrl+z